# Angular Test: Use Data Type Any to Mock Classes and Services

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular10

I am mocking services without TestBed and using Fake Classes.
Is it good practice to use a Mock with `: any` data type below?
If not I receive following errors, missing items/parameters.

I could use spyOn, but it requires TestBed, and I am trying to avoid getting rid of all executable-run time error, 'with injectable import not found' with testBed.

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-testbed-considered-harmful-3f91f647d1fd

https://dev.to/angular/unit-testing-in-angular-to-testbed-or-not-to-testbed-3g3b

```
  class ConfigMgmtServiceMock {
    modifyLkDocumentDiscardReasonPost() : Observable<any> { 
      let data = 'test';
      return of(data);
    };
  }

  let configMgmtServiceMock: any = new ConfigMgmtServiceMock();
  let snackBarMock : any = new SnackBarMock();

  beforeEach(() => {
    configMgmtServiceMock = new ConfigMgmtServiceMock();
    snackBarMock = new SnackBarMock();
    component = new DocumentDiscardLookupEditorComponent(null, configMgmtServiceMock, snackBarMock);
    component.gridRef = new GridMock() as any;
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any`, the only problem it brings - the loose of type safety, therefore if the signature of `modifyLkDocumentDiscardReasonPost` has been changed, for example it doesn't return promise anymore - then there's no typescript error.

If you want to mock classes and avoid losing the type safety you might consider usage of [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks), it allows to create mock shapes and in the same time keeps type safety, so if someone changed the type - typescript would let know developers about that in mocks too.

```js
beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(DocumentDiscardLookupEditorComponent)
  .mock(ConfigMgmtService, {
    modifyLkDocumentDiscardReasonPost: () => {
      let data = 'test';
      return of(data);
    },
  })
  .mock(SnackBar, {
     something: 'in-snack-bar',
  })
});
```